# SSH-key accepting passphrase, but moving on to password authentication? (only happens between one server pair and not a similar pair)

Tags: linux, openssh, sftp

I've been scratching my head at this for a while now. I needed to set up ssh-key based authentication for sftp. So, I generated the key files with a passphrase and sent the public key to the other vendor (I don't manage) to add to their authorized_keys file. After doing so, I attempted to sftp into their server with the command

```
sftp -vvv -i /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa xxxusernamexxx@their_server.org
```

Here was the result:

```
$ sftp -vvv -i /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa xxxusernamexxx@their_server.org
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "their_server.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to their_server.org [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 9.99 sshlib
debug1: no match: 9.99 sshlib
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to their_server.org:22 as 'xxxusernamexxx'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type DSA in file /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from their_server.org
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-ctr,twofish256-ctr,twofish-ctr,aes128-ctr,twofish128-ctr,3des-ctr,cast128-ctr,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,aes128-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-ctr,twofish256-ctr,twofish-ctr,aes128-ctr,twofish128-ctr,3des-ctr,cast128-ctr,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,aes128-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: zlib,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib,none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-dss
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1036/2048
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-dss SHA256:DB1GiNDCeVZBRU3rM8E3Igontk/9HetMfQ7fT9Trw1U
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type DSA in file /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from their_server.org
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type DSA in file /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
debug1: Host 'their_server.org' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1001/2048
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa (0x563600ba8e40), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:6n9VS4JyrsjyhbZ/fpLdQK7hizTdeABG0Lmo5Zp9j8k
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:6n9VS4JyrsjyhbZ/fpLdQK7hizTdeABG0Lmo5Zp9j8k
Enter passphrase for key '/home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa': 
<<<I entered the passphrase here>>>
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
xxxusernamexxx@their_server.org's password:
```

You can see that it completely skips over the passphrase and moves on to password authentication, without telling me why. So then I copied the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files to a different server, same subnet and the same firewall rules, and the sftp process worked just fine. The username, directory permissions, and sshd config are also the same. Here's that output:

```
$ sftp -vvv -i /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa xxxusername@their_server.org
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "their_server.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to their_server.org [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 9.99 sshlib
debug1: no match: 9.99 sshlib
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to their_server.org:22 as 'xxxusernamexxx'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type DSA in file /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from their_server.org
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-ctr,twofish256-ctr,twofish-ctr,aes128-ctr,twofish128-ctr,3des-ctr,cast128-ctr,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,aes128-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-ctr,twofish256-ctr,twofish-ctr,aes128-ctr,twofish128-ctr,3des-ctr,cast128-ctr,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,aes128-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: zlib,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib,none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-dss
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1047/2048
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-dss SHA256:DB1GiNDCeVZBRU3rM8E3Igontk/9HetMfQ7fT9Trw1U
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type DSA in file /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from their_server.org
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type DSA in file /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
debug1: Host 'their_server.org' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: bits set: 959/2048
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55fe2bcde740), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:6n9VS4JyrsjyhbZ/fpLdQK7hizTdeABG0Lmo5Zp9j8k
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:6n9VS4JyrsjyhbZ/fpLdQK7hizTdeABG0Lmo5Zp9j8k
Enter passphrase for key '/home/xxxuserxxx/.ssh/id_rsa': 
<<<I entered the passphrase here>>>
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to their_server.org ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env JAVA_HOME
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 16384 rmax 35840
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
debug2: Remote version: 3
Connected to their_server.org.
debug3: Sent message fd 3 T:16 I:1
debug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH . -> /Home/xxxusernamexxx size 0
sftp>
```

So it works from that system. I've also testing using the ssh-key to login from my server to another one of my servers (with xxxuserxxx) and it worked, so its not the configuration on my side. It seems to only be an issue between my server and their_server.org which I don't have access to the logs, and the company has been less than helpful in troubleshooting. I've tried everything I can think of, including generation new keys. Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: I've had this issue with my hoster once. As it turns out, there is a bug within SSH, that sometimes rejects the key for no reason. Their solution was to overwrite my SSH key with a copy, then it worked again. I can't tell exactly if it's the same bug hitting you, but it sounds like it. Another reason is permissions. SSH is extremly nitpicky about having chmod 700 on ~/.ssh and 600 on everything within. On my Synology NAS, I had to 600 my whole /home directory to make it work.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck! I even tried to move all permission in the whole user's home directory to 600, still no luck. Also, I think the permissions are okay because I can use the keys to get into another one of my boxes. I'll look into this bug you're talking about though!

Comment: @BadSnowflake Have you reported this bug?

Comment: @Paradox No, since I don't know the specifics. It is a web hoster and they don't know what causes it. I can't report a bug with no information how to reproduce it.